# Angular - Set up a path variable that changes per page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am ng-including partials in different portions of my site, at different folder levels. Because of that, I need to be able to set, per page, a root relative folder path so that assets such as partials and images can be found. For example, something like this, but correctly:

index.html:

```
<div class="homepage">
    <ng-include src="'patterns/header.html'">
</div>
```

but also be able to access that same partial as below:

/individuals/header/index.html

```
<div class="individual">
    <ng-include src="'../../patterns/header.html'">
</div>
```

Is there a method for setting something like

```
pathIs = '../../patterns/'
```

that would be used on the individual page like so:

```
<ng-include="{{pathIs}} + 'header.html'">
```

And if so, where would I do that? Directory structure below:

```
index.html
|
patterns/
--------header.html
|
individuals/
--------header/
----------------index.html
```

(I am including header.html in both index.html as well as in individuals/header/index.html)

Comment: I think you made a type `nginclude` should be `ng-include` though its not an answer

Comment: Are you able to just use the full relative path (ie, `patterns/header/index.html') in all ng-includes? It seems like in both that and the ../.. case you are required to know the directory structure

Comment: Since I am calling to the same file from different levels in the directory, I need to use the ../.. syntax. I'll add the directory structure above to make that more clear.

Comment: Gotcha. I should have been clearer too - What I meant to say was that if you were to set `<base href="/">` in the <head> of your document, I believe you should be able to use the full relative path from your serving directory regardless of where the file doing the <ng-include> is.

Comment: Wow, you're right, completely forgot about <base> and that does exactly what I need. Thank you! Now to figure out how to switch between dev and production base href values....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mrusinak mentioned, setting

```
<base href="/">
```

does what I need it to do. Now I just need to figure out how to switch that between my dev and production environments.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that, one way is storing that relative path in a service, such as example:

```
services.factory('ConfigurationService', function(){    
    var root = {};

    root.getWebappContextName = function () {
        return "/myapp";
    };      

    return root;    
});
```

In your controlller:

```
$scope.getTemplatePath = function () {
   return ConfigurationService.getWebappContextName() + "/myspecificpath/;
}
$scope.templatePath = $scope.getTemplatePath();
```

in your html:

```
<div id="header" data-ng-include data-src="templatePath + 'header.html'"></div>
```